# Custom error pages when using IIS as a reverse proxy

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, custom-errors

I've configured IIS to act as a reverse proxy for a development server (dartlang's pub serve if you're curious).  I'm doing this because the development server doesn't support custom error pages and I need them to be working locally.  I've set up the custom error page in IIS but it's not serving it -- it's passing through the default 404 page from the source server.  Is it possible to make the reverse proxy serve it's own custom page for 404 errors?

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but here you go: when using IIS 7+ as a reverse proxy, you can configure it to use its own error pages (custom or otherwise) by adding the following to web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="Replace"/>
</system.webServer>
```

More info in [the docs...](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/#configuration)